# Explain a code of finding nth Fibonacci Number

Tags: javascript, loops, math, fibonacci

I am new to problem-solving. I found a code for finding the `nth Fibonacci number`. But I am confused about the work of some variables.

```
var fibonacci = function (n) {
  let prev = 0,
    cur = 1,
    temp;

  for (let i = 1; i < n; i++) {
    temp = cur;
    cur = cur + prev;
    prev = temp;
  }

  return cur;
};
```

can you describe what the `temp` `cur` and `prev` variable is doing? especially the `temp` variable.
**Thank you!**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't feel bad, that code is quite difficult to follow. Here is a simpler version that uses new javascript features to avoid the `temp` variable:

```js
function fib(n) {
  let prev = 0;
  let curr = 1;
  for(let i=1; i<n; i++) {
    [prev, curr] = [curr, curr + prev];
  }
  return curr;
}
```

Or, without using the new javascript feature to allow swapping, it can be more clearly coded as follows:

```js
function fib(n) {
  let prev = 0;
  let curr = 1;
  for(let i=1; i<n; i++) {
    let next = curr + prev; 
    prev = curr; 
    curr = next;
  }
  return curr;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

- temp means temporary
- cur means current
- prev means previous

temp is needed because you have to assign cur as cur + prev and at same time you need to assign prev as cur.

Without temp if you do `cur = cur + prev` you won't be able to assign `prev = cur` because cur is already changed.

In other words to update cur you need prev and to update prev you need cur, with help of temp we can save old cur as temp and get new cur using old prev, and then using temp update prev.

Here is an example:

if we have such values:

```
let prev = 1,
    cur = 2,
    temp;
```

at loop we will do

```
temp = cur; // temp is 2
cur = cur + prev; // cur is 3
prev = temp; // prev is 2
```

if instead at loop we didn't use temp:

```
cur = cur + prev; //cur is 3
prev = cur; // prev is 3
```

prev is 3 which is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Basically Fibonacci numbers are the sum of the two previous Fibonacci numbers starting with two 1's.

Meaning, that the for loop cycles `n` times through the loop to get the `nth` Fibonacci number.
All the code does is to store the `(n-2)th` number into a variable, the `(n-1)th` number into the second variable und calculating the `nth` number by adding `(n-2)th` + `(n-1)th`.

After that it starts over with the `(n-1)th` being the `(n-2)th` and the `nth` being the `(n-1)th`.